# How to attach a React element to a property on a JavaScript object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a React Element below called `Info` and attached it to a Javascript object (`myObj`):

```
let Info = (
    <Info type="green" />
);

let myObj = {
    ReactComp: Info
};
```

Then I want to use the above object (`myObj`) to render the `Info` component:

```
const ComponentToRenderInfoIn = (props) => {
    const { ReactComp } = props;
    return (
        <ReactComp />
    );
}

<ComponentToRenderInfoIn  {...myObj} />
```

In the above code, it's saying that for `ReactComp` it got an object for some reason even though I set it to a React element above:

> Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two things you'll need to look out for with the example you provided.

1. Is the definition of `Info` intended to be recursive? I would rename one of these so they are not the same. Below I renamed the component `InfoComponent`.
2. You are effectively rendering the component twice. For example, if you substituted in the value of `Info` into `<ReactComp />` we'd have the logic that is equivalent to `<<Info type="green" />/>` *(this isn't valid syntax but trying to explain why what you currently have isn't working as expected)*. This can be fixed in a few ways,

   1. This example updates `ComponentToRenderInfoIn` to directly return `ReactComp`.
   2. You could also update `Info` to be a component as well: `let Info = () => <InfoComponent type="green" />;`.
   3. Or you could update `Info` to reference the component directly (`let Info = InfoComponent`) and then update the return value of `ComponentToRenderInfoIn` to be `<ReactComp type="green" />`.

```js
const InfoComponent = () => <div>INFO!</div>;

let Info = <InfoComponent type="green" />;

let myObj = {
  ReactComp: Info
};

const ComponentToRenderInfoIn = props => {
  const { ReactComp } = props;
  return ReactComp;
};
```